# Scala function to parse json with time fields to appropriate case classes. How can I write this better?

Tags: scala

I have the below function which populates different time-related case classes based on what is present in the JSON input.

```
def parseTime(timeJson: JsValue) = {
   val day = (timeJson \ "day").getOrElse(JsString("")).as[JsString].value.toInt
   val week = (timeJson \ "month").getOrElse(JsString("")).as[JsString].value.toInt
   val month = (timeJson \ "month").getOrElse(JsString("")).as[JsString].value.toInt
   val year = (timeJson \ "year").getOrElse(JsString("")).as[JsString].value.toInt
   if (day != "") {
     YearMonthDay(
       year = year,
       month = month,
       day = day)
   }
   else if (month != "") {
     YearMonth(
       year = year,
       month = month
     )
   }
   else if (week != "") {
     YearWeek(
       year = year,
       week = week
     )
   }
   else {
     Year(year)
   }
 }
```

Is there a cleaner way to check whether specific fields are present in my tuple of 4 values (day, week, month, year)

Comment: The posted code lacks the `import` statements necessary for it to compile.

Comment: There is [`scala.util.parsing.json.JSON`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/parsing/json/JSON$.html) as well as [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/); you seem to be [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]: tag accordingly.

Comment: Not related to the json, but you can remove most of those braces. `!= ""` could be `.nonEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

Let this be the definition of your Date types:

```
sealed trait Date {
  def year: Int
}

case class Year(year: Int) extends Date
case class YearMonth(year: Int, month: Int) extends Date
case class YearWeek(year: Int, week: Int) extends Date
case class YearMonthDay(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) extends Date
```

In your question there are problems when value is not defined, or when it is empty string, or when value is present, but it is not a number. So you can use common function `readInt` to read optional integer from JSON. In case if value is not present or if value is empty or non-integer, the result of function will be `scala.util.Failure`.

```
  def parseDate(dateJson: JsValue): Try[Date] = {
    def readInt(fieldName: String): Try[Int] =
      (dateJson \ fieldName).asOpt[String].filter(_.nonEmpty).map(x => Try(x.toInt))
        .getOrElse(Failure(new IllegalArgumentException(s"$fieldName is empty")))

    val maybeDay: Try[Int] = readInt("day")
    val maybeWeek: Try[Int] = readInt("week")
    val maybeMonth: Try[Int] = readInt("month")
    val maybeYear: Try[Int] = readInt("year")

    maybeYear.map { year: Int =>
      maybeMonth match {
        case Success(month) => maybeDay match {
          case Success(day) => YearMonthDay(year, month, day)
          case _ => YearMonth(year, month)
        }
        case _ => maybeWeek match {
          case Success(week) => YearWeek(year, week)
          case _ => Year(year)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My tests:

```
val date1 = JsObject(Map("year" -> JsString("2001"), "month" -> JsString("11"), "day" -> JsString("30")))
println(parseDate(date1)) // => Success(YearMonthDay(2001,11,30))
val date2 = JsObject(Map("year" -> JsString("2001"), "month" -> JsString("11")))
println(parseDate(date2)) // => Success(YearMonth(2001,11))
val date3 = JsObject(Map("year" -> JsString("2001"), "week" -> JsString("51")))
println(parseDate(date3)) // => Success(YearWeek(2001,51))
val date4 = JsObject(Map("year" -> JsString("")))
println(parseDate(date4)) // => Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: year is empty)
```

Sorry for my English